# Using component from exports in a module

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have `UserService` which is required by `UserModule` and then added to `exports`

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common'
import {TypeOrmModule} from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import {User} from './user.entity'
import {UserService} from './user.service'

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  components: [UserService],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule{}
```

I then have an `AuthModule` that needs to use the `UserService` which does this:

```
import * as passport from 'passport'
import * as PassportAzureAD from 'passport-azure-ad'
import * as session from 'express-session'
import {
  Module,
  NestModule,
  MiddlewaresConsumer,
  RequestMethod,
} from '@nestjs/common'
import {Logger} from '@nestjs/common'
import {UserModule} from '../user/user.module'

@Module({
  imports: [UserModule],
  components: [],
  controllers: []
})
export class AuthModule implements NestModule{
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer){
      // SNIP
      // How to use `UserService` here
  }
}
```

How do I use the `UserService` here? The [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) say:

> Now each module which would import the CatsModule (we need to put CatsModule into the imports array) has access to the CatsService and will share the same instance with all of the modules which are importing this module too.

But gives no example as to how you would.

Comment: If you want to IOC import it i think you need to add it to `imports`? `imports: [UserModule, UserService]`

Comment: Then I need `import {UserService}...`, doesnt that defeat the object of importing everything into the `UserModule`

Comment: ah i see, im actually not really an angular developer. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules maybe use as: `UserModule.UserService` or `AuthModule.UserModule.UserService`?

Comment: This is nestjs (https://nestjs.com/). `UserModule` is defined but no variation of `UserModule.UserService` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exported `UserService` needs to be imported into `AuthModule` in its constructor like so:

```
@Module({
  imports: [UserModule],
  components: [],
  controllers: []
})
export class AuthModule implements NestModule{
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService
  ) {}

  public configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer){
    this.userService
  }
}
```

More on dependancy injection here:

- https://docs.nestjs.com/components
- https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dependency-injection